# Passing function to child which contains toggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I'm trying to add checkbox to my react component but when I try to render after I pull from the data from fetch it says that function is undifined

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined at WeatherInfo
```

The values come from redux reducer

This is my App.js

```
toggleCheckboxChange() {
   console.log("a");
}

render() {
  const { cityName, nameOfCity, weatherDescription, windSpeed, temperature, maxTemperature, minTemperature, toogleValue} = this.props;


let weatherInfo;

weatherInfo = <WeatherInfo
      nameOfCity={nameOfCity}
      weatherDescription={weatherDescription}
      windSpeed={windSpeed}
      temperature={temperature}
      maxTemperature={maxTemperature}
      minTemperature={minTemperature}
      toggleValue={toggleValue}
      onChange={() => this.toggleCheckboxChange()}
  />;
```

WeatherInfo component

```
const WeatherInfo = (props) => (
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>{props.nameOfCity}</li>
        <li>{props.weatherDescription}</li>
        <li>{props.windSpeed} m/s </li>
        <li>{props.temperature} °C</li>
        <li>{props.maxTemperature}°C</li>
        <li>{props.minTemperature}°C</li>

        <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={props.toogleValue}
            onChange={this.props.toggleCheckboxChange}
        />
    </ul>
</div>
);
```

how can I pass function to onChange in child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `Functional Component`, `this` keyword will not be available inside that, use the function directly, like this:

`props.function`

Write it like this:

```
const WeatherInfo = (props) => (
   <div>
      <ul>
         <li>{props.nameOfCity}</li>
         <li>{props.weatherDescription}</li>
         <li>{props.windSpeed} m/s </li>
         <li>{props.temperature} °C</li>
         <li>{props.maxTemperature}°C</li>
         <li>{props.minTemperature}°C</li>

         <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={props.myPokemon}
            onChange={(e)=>props.toggleCheckboxChange(e)}
         />
      </ul>
   </div>
);
```

Check this example:

```js
class App extends React.Component { 

    change(e){
      console.log(e.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child change={this.change.bind(this)}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

let Child = (props)=>{
  return <input onChange={(e)=>props.change(e)}/>
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'/>
```

Check this article: https://www.reactenlightenment.com/react-state/8.4.html